# Windows 10 - permissions to one user who belongs to two groups

Tags: windows-10, permissions

(Windows 10)

I have a user (u1) who belongs to 2 groups (g1, g2).

g1 cannot have access to one folder  (f1) but g2 can have acces to f1.

How can I grant all access for u1 to f1? (as Windows says that deny rights are greater than allow rights)
Thx.

Comment: Deny refers to actually setting up deny rules. Just because you're in two groups where one has and one doesn't have access doesn't mean there is an implicit deny. The rules are additive so unless you define actual deny rules for g2 the membership in g1 would be enough for u1 to gain the respective permissions. Check the "Effective Permissions" tool in the advanced permission tab.

Answer (score 0):

The rules for resolving permissions conflicts are as follows:

- Deny takes precedence over Allow.
- Direct permissions (explicit permissions) have precedence over
  inherited permissions from a parent or group.
- Permissions inherited from near predecessors take precedence over those inherited from distant ones. So parent folder permissions have precedence over
  grandparent folder.
- Permissions from different user groups that are of the same type (both being
  Deny or Allow) are cumulative.

In that case, direct permissions given to user u1 will have precedence over
those inherited from the groups, and that's your solution
(the only one that I can see).

Comment: I have set full rights to u1 directly. But effective permissions show that u1 have no access to the folder. If I give only read access to g1, u1 will have only read access in effective permission. There is something I miss here.

Comment: The rules can be confusing. Better add to your post more info about the exact permissions of the groups and folder.

Comment: the rules are : for one group : full access, or no access to one folder.